# What is the difference between running inside and outside VS debugger?

Tags: c++, debugging

I have a program. If it is running inside Visual C++ 2008 debugger, then everything is OK. But if the debug version is running outside the debugger, then it will not work. So I just wonder what is the main difference between two situations?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "it will not work"?!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic guide that explains pretty much everything that you need to know about the differences between debug and release builds: [Surviving the Release version](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/548/Surviving-the-Release-Version)

Comment: While the link may be useful, an answer should be self contained. As it is not, this is more of a comment.

Comment: @StoryTeller Sorry, I'm just starting out here and wasn't aware of this. I'll keep this in mind in the future. Given that, this particular question too broad, gives little information, and to answer it as such within a post, it's going to be quite hard.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to run the program using Debug ("F5") in visual studio,

You are probably experiencing some form of missing dependencies such as missing .dll files or environment variables. 
You can verify this opening up a Command line and run `vcvarsall.bat` followed by your program. Alternatively run your program using the Visual Studio Command Line found in the Window Start Menu.

Depending on your installation `vcvarsall.bat` is usually located at:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio \VC\vcvarsall.bat

If your program still fails to execute, you can using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find out what other possible dependencies that your program might have.

However, without more details on the problem that you are experiencing, I can only provide you with some other possible beginner examples:

> No Pop Error messages, Console Application, Double Click program with
>   no visible reaction.

Console applications by default does not keeps its console active after finishing execution. So if your program is too fast, you probably can't see it "running". You can add `system("pause");` at the end of your program prevent it from closing immediately.

> No Pop Error messages, Windows Application, No GUI code, Double Click
>   program with no visible reaction.

Your program is probably running in the background already. Verify this using the task manager and see if the process is listed there. If you use `printf` or `std::out`, you need to run your program using the command line in order to see the output.